# Not able to set Textbox text using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Trying to set this textbox

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.IndicationCalculatorNewGroupName, new {propertyName = "IndicationCalculatorNewGroupName", onchange = "UpdateField(this);", dontRegisterNewIndication = true })%>
```

like this:

```
$("#IndicationCalculatorNewGroupName").val('-- Enter new Group Name --');
```

I am accessing it fine using that Id and everything when I do other things like `$("#IndicationCalculatorNewGroupName").show();` but not when I try and set it's text.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the onchange event is getting triggered and causing issues. Temporarily remove it to see if that is the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#IndicationCalculatorNewGroupName').val('-- Enter new Group Name --');` is the correct jQuery syntax, so the issue is something else.

Here is a jsfiddle showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/bdL2Q/

Can you provide additional details please?

What is the markup generated by `Html.TextBoxFor`?
What is the exact jQuery code you are trying to run? (Is it as simple as the snippet you posted?)

Comment: Found the issue. But you get it cuz you knew syntax was correct ;)